# Erro Requisição AJAX - não consigo manipular o retorno

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenho a seguinte requisição AJAX:

```
function getJson(link) {
    var retorno;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: link,
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data)
        {
            alert(data);
            retorno = data;
        }
    });
    return retorno;
}
```

Quando executo ele mostra um json na aba Network do Chrome. Mas nn consigo manipular usando a variavel data nem num alert nem no proprio retorno. Tem algo de errado com o código?

***Alert na variavel data***

[image: undefined]

***Aba Network***

[image: Network]

Acho que o erro ta aq:

> "Failed to load: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '127.0.1.1'; is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: acredito que seja na linguagem de fundo o problema, se não no alert teria aparecido [Object object]

Comment: Qual é a programação desse retorno?

Comment: Não sei dizer, faço uma requisição ao Trivago.

Comment: Verifique na aba Network, no devtools do chrome ou firefox, basta apertar o F12, veja oque o request esta retornando.

Comment: Na aba Network aparece o json que seria o retorno. Mas nn consigo manipular ele através da variável data (definida no success).

Comment: Acho que o erro ta aq: "Failed to load: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '127.0.1.1'; is therefore not allowed access."